# wamp - syntax error on like 615: Unrecognized parameter type "Type"

Tags: syntax-error, wamp

After successful installation of wamp3.1.4 and after initial setup done and all working good.

When browsing the wamp sys tray icon and moving out, an error message popped out.

[image: Aestan Tray Menu]

All works fine until I shutdown and log back into my WIN764bitOS and try to start wamp again.
The same error pops up and does not show up the wamp sys tray icon. 
I hope the apache and mysql is running at the background.

But then I like to know why does this happen.

Comment: Happens to me too, have you managed to solve this issue?

Comment: @KristapsGaidulis - Not yet.

Comment: I just reinstalled it and now it works fine. weird though, because I didn't play around with any config files

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was "PhpMyAdmin 5.0.2 not compatible with PHP 8.0.9". I had to upgrade the PhpMyAdmin to 5.1.1 which supports PHP 8. For updating PhpMyAdmin on WAMP, visit [WAMPServer Backup Repo](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/?lang=en).